# Type object 'Food101' has no attribute 'load_data'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

food = tfds.image.food101.Food101
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = food.load_data()
```

and I got the following error:

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-92f141508c7c> in <module>()
            9 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
         1  0 food = tfds.image.food101.Food101
      ---> 11 (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = 
      food.load_data()
AttributeError: type object 'Food101' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

What should I do to overcome this error?

Comment: According [to the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load) the way to load a tf dataset is (for example, mnist): `dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)` How did you find the code you're currently using to load the data?

Comment: tensorflow website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tensorflow page, the correct way for you to load the Dataset is:

```py
data, info = tfds.load("desired_dataset", with_info=True)
```

So, in your code you should load it with:

```py
food, info = tfds.load("food101", with_info=True)
```

If that does not work, **load it's builder**:

```py
builder = tfds.builder("tfds.image.food101.Food101")
builder.download_and_prepare()
datasets = builder.as_dataset()
```

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview)
[Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/food101?hl=th)

Comment: You need to use [this version](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/tree/master/tensorflow_datasets/image)

Answer (score 0):

Code to get the TensorFlow dataset loaded will be something like this:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

food_images, food_labels = tfds.load(name='food101', split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
```

But unfortunately, in the current latest version of TensorFlow Datasets (1.1.0), Food101 dataset is not present.
You can check it [1.1.0 GitHub version](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/tree/v1.1.0/tensorflow_datasets/image) that food101.py file is missing, but if you change to master branch, the food101.py will be present. If you need food101.py, you will have to build TensorFlow Dataset from source or else download the dataset directly from the download link.

Comment: what is mean build from scoure ?

Comment: Build from source means cloning from repository and then building it instead of downloading pre-built packages through PyPi